Do I need a level shifter in between if I want to connect 3.3 V output signals to TTL-compatible inputs?
Concrete case: The AM26LS31 is a TTL-compatible differential line driver.
It has the following recommended input conditions:

Is it OK to supply it with a 3.3 V powered logic device whose output has the following specifications?

For my understanding, it should basically work fine. Is it anyway a bad practice to design like this? Should a level shifter be used in between for stable/professional design?

The diff line driver accepts a minimum of 2 V as a Logic-Hi input, and a maximum of 0.8 V as a Logic-Low input. There are some characterisations in the datasheet for 2.7 V and 7 V input so it accepts anything within the 2 - 7 V range.
Your logic device is capable of outputting a minimum of 2.4 V (with 12 mA of source current) for Logic-HI and a maximum of 0.4 V (with 12 mA of sink current) for Logic-Low. These are well within the line driver's acceptable input range.
So yes, you can use them together without any level translator.

The numbers match.
The typical high-level output voltage of a TTL output is near 3.3 V, so in general, you can connect the output of any 3.3 V CMOS device directly to a TTL input.
(The high-level input current of the AM26LS31 is less than 20 µA, so the actual output voltage of your 3.3 V device will be near 3.3 V. In any case, even 2.4 V would be enough.)
